# Stripe usage with token

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for payment for the first time. While clicking on Pay button when we enter email, card number, date and cvc, I get an error message which asks me to activate my account. I learned that it takes all this information and returns a token which we can save in the database. How do I get a token in return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for thinking of using Stripe! I work on Support there and can help.

If you're getting that error message about activating your account, it's probably because you're using live keys but don't have a live, active account yet. If you email into Stripe support using the email address associated with your Stripe account, I could look into this for you further (e.g., looking at your logs and status).

As for the token, the token is a short-term representation of the customer's credit card information. You wouldn't need to store the token in your database. You should instead use it to process a charge, or create a customer, and then ignore it (because, at that point, the token will have been consumed).

For more, see this page in our docs:

- https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

Cheers,
Larry

Comment: Thanks Larry. I understand what you said but we need to store atleast something about the user right for monthly transactions from his account? I am using Stripe for the first time and that's why am still learning to use it.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. Yes, you'd want to store the customer ID on your site, as part of whatever else you're storing about each customer. The Stripe customer ID can then be used to interact with the Stripe API.

If you're doing monthly billing, however, you can just sign the customer up to a plan:

- https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/subscriptions